# Why is getRange() not getting the range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot get this varRange to work correctly. in .getRanger says it cannot find range. the format is correct i think. This is also my first time asking for help in this before and i am self taught so bear with me please.

```js
function CopyPaste1() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var as = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var varRange = as.getRange('C28').getValue();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Material Order'), true);
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange(varRange).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);  
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
cell C28= '\'1805 Material Order\'!A1:I27'
```

The Error i am getting is Range Not found Line 11

Comment: checking the docs, i don't think you've entered the correct parameters: `method getRange(row, column, optNumRows, optNumColumns)
` It says you need at least 2 params while you have one. Try replacing `var varRange = as.getRange('C28').getValue();` with `var varRange = as.getRange('C','28').getValue();`

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy that won't work.  If you want to use `C28` then use it like this `as.getRange('C28')` otherwise it has to be `as.getRange(28,3)`

Comment: `getRange` could use only one parameter, as it's shown in your code. What is the value of `C28`? Does it contains a text representing a range reference, a formula or other thing?

Answer (score 1):

`var varRange = as.getRange('C28').getValue();`

varRange is a value not a range.

This expression `spreadsheet.getRange(varRange)` requires a range but varRange is not a range.

Oh I see what you're getting at now. I'd probably just break it up into two cells and use a getSheetByName() and a getRange() separately.    There's probably a way around that but I'm not sure what it is and I don't really care.